# Call argument in another condition

Tags: python

I'm trying to call objects from a list which is in another part of a condition, which obviously doesn't work.
Can someone explain me how I can do that properly?

```
def doSLM(btn, *args):
    if btn == 'btnBuild':
        allObj = buildSnowLayers()
        # Let's say that:
        # allObj = [ground1, snow1, ground2, snow2, ground3, snow3]
        allGrounds = allObj[::2]
        # So we have:
        # allGrounds = [ground1, ground2, ground3]
        allSnowLayers = allObj[1::2]
        # And:
        # allSnowLayers = [snow1, snow2, snow3]
    elif btn == 'btnClearScene':
        # I need to pass 'allSnowLayers' in this part of
        # the condition, but how?
        for obj in allSnowLayers:
            clearLayer(obj) # This function simply delete the object
```

**Edit:** add some details. Sorry if it's not clear, I'm still learning...

Comment: There isn't enough information here to help you yet. The way this is written, there's no way to tell exactly what you want to do, except define a value based on a value that is not defined.

Comment: I added some details, hope it's better.

Comment: What are you doing with `allSnowLayers` in the first case ? Are you storing it somewhere ? And how is your function used ?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly prevents you from creating the list outside of the condition? If you need to access it no matter how the condition gets resolved, you might as well define it in the correct scope.

```
def doSLM(btn, *args):
    allObj = buildSnowLayers()
    allGrounds = allObj[::2]
    allSnowLayers = allObj[1::2]
    if btn == 'btnClearScene':
        # I need to pass 'allSnowLayers' in this part of
        # the condition, but how?
        for obj in allSnowLayers:
            clearLayer(obj) # This function simply delete the object
```

If you need, you can empty the intermediate lists after you are done by assigning [] or None to them. If you really need to populate the list only under some circumstances, you can define it as an empty list outside of the condition and then populate it inside.

```
def doSLM(btn, *args):
    allSnowLayers = []
    if btn == 'btnBuild':
        allObj = buildSnowLayers()
        # Let's say that:
        # allObj = [ground1, snow1, ground2, snow2, ground3, snow3]
        allGrounds = allObj[::2]
        # So we have:
        # allGrounds = [ground1, ground2, ground3]
        allSnowLayers = allObj[1::2]
        # And:
        # allSnowLayers = [snow1, snow2, snow3]
    elif btn == 'btnClearScene':
        # I need to pass 'allSnowLayers' in this part of
        # the condition, but how?
        for obj in allSnowLayers:
            clearLayer(obj) # This function simply delete the object
```

Comment: Ok thank you, I was a bit lost ; I think I should change all the code because I can't do it this way. The fact is that I have an UI with two buttons calling my function and I need to execute a different function for each button (which is why I have this condition), considering that the first button will necessarily be executed before the second one.

Comment: Yeah, looks like you might want to rethink your code structure. Read up on variable scopes in python Here, for example, http://python-textbok.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Variables_and_Scope.html

As a shortcut though, look at my second solution. It seems like it might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I *guess* you're learning about [scope](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) for the first time. Describing variable scoping in general is beyond a simple StackOverflow question scope, but you need to determine a way to access allSnowLayers objects from outside the scope of this function. Consider using a class and a class property, for one example. Then, the behaviors of each button can be handled by individual methods instead of a large if/else switch.

For example:

```
class SLM:
    def __init__(self):
        layers = buildSnowLayers()
        self.layers = layers
        self.grounds = layers[::2]
        self.snow_layers = layers[1::2]
    def clearScene(self):
        for obj in self.snow_layers:
            clearLayer(obj)
```

In the above example, instantiating the SLM class creates an SLM object that is perpetually aware of the state of its "layers", "grounds" and "snow_layers" properties until it is destroyed. If you invoke `clearScene` like

```
slm = SLM()
slm.clearScene()
```

then `slm` will apply `clearLayer` on each of the members of the `snow_layers` property. It still knows about that property because it's a member of the object, not just a function variable.